# Dimensional analysis on diffusion equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, dimensional-analysis, diffusion

I was studying the equation of motion for the probability density function of the
position coordinates of the Brownian particles, also known as the **Smoluchowski Equation** (SE).

Particularly, I came across:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \rho (r,t) = D_o [\nabla^2 \rho (r,t) + \beta \nabla \rho (r,t) \int dr' [\nabla  V (|r-r'|)] \rho (r',t) g(r,r',t)]$$

Which is the SE form for interacting particles.

Where:

1) $\rho (r,t)$ is the probability density function.

2) $D_o$ is the diffusion coefficient.

3)
$$\nabla = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}$$

4)
$$\beta = \frac{1}{k_\mathrm BT}$$

5) $V (|r-r'|)$ is the potential.

6) $g(r,r',t)$ is the pair correlation function.

I got curious and wanted to verify this equation using **dimensional analysis**.

We know that:

$$[D_o] = \frac{L^2}{T}$$

$$[\beta] = \frac{T^2}{ML^2}$$

$$[\rho] = \frac{1}{L T}$$

$$[\nabla] = \frac{1}{L}$$

$$[g] = \frac{1}{L^2T}$$

Note that dimensions of $\rho$ come from the fact that the integral of the probability density function over its entire support is 1. I used the same reasoning with $g$.

Based on this information I got on the left hand side:

$$\frac{1}{LT^2}$$

**My struggle is triggered by the second term on the right hand side of the equation**, as I got as the final result:

$$\frac{1}{LT^2} = \frac{1}{LT^2} + \frac{1}{L^6T^3}$$

I think I may be missing something related to the dimensions of the correlation function...

Comment: Are you working in three spatial dimensions, or one? The units of $\rho$ don’t look like a 3D or a 1D probability density to me.

Comment: The gradient operator produces a vector, but it isn’t getting contracted with anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [pair correlation function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_distribution_function) is defined to be dimensionless. The probability density is defined such that its integral *over all space* is unity for any time $t$. So, if you are thinking only of one spatial dimension, both sides are $L^{-1}T^{-1}$, while in three dimensions both sides are $L^{-3}T^{-1}$.

Actually, in the context that I have seen this version of the Smoluchowski equation (papers by Jan Dhont and colleagues on dynamics in colloidal systems), $\rho(r,t)$ is the single particle density, not the single particle probability density. The difference is simply that the integral of $\rho(r,t)$ over all space gives the total number of particles in the system, $N$, rather than unity. This does not affect the dimensional analysis at all, but I thought I should clarify.

Comment: @JD_PM please note my second paragraph, added for clarity after you accepted the answer.